# Iterative methods for linear system with non-diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a linear system
\begin{align*}
    \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
        1 & 2 & 1 & -1 \\
        3 & 2 & 4 & 4 \\
        4 & 4 & 3 & 4 \\
        2 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\
    \end{array}\right]
    \left[\begin{array}{c}
        w \\ x \\ y \\z
    \end{array}\right] =
    \left[\begin{array}{c}
        5 \\ 16 \\ 22 \\ 15
    \end{array}\right],
\end{align*}
whose matrix $\bf{A}$ is not diagonally dominant. What are the iterative methods that can be used to find the solution? I have tried Jacobi method, Gauss-Seidel method and SOR method but nothing works (the output diverges). The answer is ${\bf x}=[16,-6,-2,-3]^T$.

Comment: Why do you want to use an iterative method on a dense 4x4 matrix in the first place? What is the underlying problem?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I had a large sparse system from Poisson equation and was considering a few alternatives to solve the system. This is my toy problem. What methods would you suggest for this dense system/matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see your equation as $f(u)=Au-b$, with $f(u)=0$. You can use some numerical method to solve it. One way is to use the minimization problem
$$\min_u g(u),\qquad g(u)=\frac{1}{2}\|f(u)\|^2.$$ This gives you the equation $$0=\nabla g(u)=A^T(Au-b)\quad \text{ or } \quad A^TAu=A^Tb$$ which gives you the possible minimizers.

To your matrix $A$ and vector $b$, you can use the [conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) to solve $$A^TAu=A^Tb,$$ and it [gives you the answer in four steps](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/2OmHyUE6x5m).

If you prefer to play with more steps, you can try [gradient descent method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).

You can find more searching for "[\(Au=b\)  gradient](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28Au%3Db%5C%29%20%20gradient%20) " on SearchOnMath.

**Note:** If you use the gradient descent method to minimize $h(u)=u^TAu-2u^Tb$ directly, you are going in the direction $$\frac{du}{dt}=- \nabla h(u)=-2(Au-b),$$ which is [unstable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory#Non-linear_autonomous_systems), since $A$ has one negative eigenvalue and three positive ones.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the links provided. I learnt about these two methods briefly before, but didn't use them since the matrix was not symmetric. I didn't know we can use CG to non-symmetric matrix. Hence, I just tried a few basic methods such as Jacobi, Gauss-Seidel and SOR.

Comment: That's good if it helps you. I agree that a good method is usually problem-based, as pointed out by @FedericoPoloni.

Comment: Here is a particular discussion example "[Solve this specific large sparse system of linear equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180688/solve-this-specific-large-sparse-system-of-linear-equations)".

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestions. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest not to use CG on the normal equations as suggested in the other answer, as it converts your system into one with squared condition number $\kappa(A)^2$, which will negatively affect your accuracy.

There is a different Krylov-space-based method that works for nonsymmetric systems, [GMRES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_minimal_residual_method).

Remarks on convergence:

- Today Krylov-based methods are typically preferred to classical iterative methods such as Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel, unless one is severely constrained by the hardware architecture.
- On a $4\times 4$ system GMRES will converge in 4 iterations, and overall it will be slower than any reasonable direct method.
- Unfortunately there is little you can infer about the convergence for larger matrices from this $4\times 4$ experiment, since the first three iterations are too few to get a glimpse of the convergence curve.
- As with CG, the real trick of the trade for a large system is preconditioning it, i.e., turning it into a modified system $PAx=Pb$ with better convergence properties. This is a huge research topic, and the best preconditioners are often problem-based.

Comment: thanks very much for your comments. I will have have a look at GMRES!